# Optimization of solr indexing by removing redundancy

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I'm working on a production scenario, currently having less data, which is now going to be in Millions.
Scenario: I'm having a folder that contains multiple students' data (student_id, rol etc).
Now, one student's data can be in different folders (Yes its our requirement). At current system, all the details of student are indexed under each folder. As data is very less, so duplicacy doesn't create problem right now. But, if we continue at same process, then same student's data will be indexed multiple times (depends on number of folders containing that student data), thereby increasing redundancy and index size.

I want to minify the index size and dont want data redundancy.Please provide a simpler solution for achieving this task in Solr.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a uniqueKey field defined, any document with the same key as a previous document will overwrite the existing document, and you'll avoid having duplicates in your index.

If you don't have a unique value that identify your students, you're going to have a hard time merging anything (outside of Solr as well), and you might have to write some custom code to merge entries appropriately outside of Solr.

Comment: I think I couldnt make you understand my scenario. At current system, all the details of student are indexed under **each folder**. I mean, folder1 have student1 data(s_id, rol etc), and same student1 data may also exist in folder2 and so on. Now I wanted to ask that, when data are of same student then why to index each time, under different folder? Is there any way that we should index it once and use it again in other folder. Note that, we have **student_data inside folder**